# How to check in iPhone Simulator a downloaded file?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios-simulator, afnetworking

I'm working on downloading files and it seems to work, because I checked simulator's folders that indeed I did download files. Here is my download method:

```
NSString *JSON = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:params
                                                                                options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted
                                                                                  error:&error]
                                       encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *data = @{@"data": JSON};

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *path = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"download"];
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
//manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *op = [manager POST:server
                                parameters:data
                                  success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                                      NSLog(@"successful download to %@", path);
                                      [blockView removeFromSuperview];
                                      UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
                                      [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]]];
                                      [self.view addSubview:webView];

                                  } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                      NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
                                      [blockView removeFromSuperview];
                                      UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Download failed!"
                                                                                      message:error.localizedDescription
                                                                                     delegate:self
                                                                            cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                                            otherButtonTitles:nil];
                                      [alert show];
                                  }];
op.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:path append:NO];
```

And now I have two problems:

1. before download all I know are document id, so I don't know if it is pdf or png or else - shouldn't I do something about it? Ideally I would add proper extension, but that is known after download is finished...
2. how should I test in simulator in order to check if I can read downloaded files on  device (or simulator in that case)?

**edit**
response is always `application/octet-stream`

**edit2**
solution below - but still I want to know how to check/display/send via mail/use downloaded files on real device?

tia

Comment: The status data probably tells you the file type.

Comment: by status data you mean... ?

Comment: The request status data.  I don't use that particular interface, so I don't know the specifics, but there is a status string returned on the transfer, and part of the info in it is usually the file type (as a "mime type").

Comment: it's always application/octet-stream, that's why I'm trying to figure out how to save it properly

Comment: https://kb.iu.edu/data/agtj.html

Comment: read it, but problem is that `NSOutputStrem` bit is before I even know what I'm downloading, so how could I get it from (not existing yet) `filename` ?

Comment: You can always rename the file after you download it.

Comment: Find document directory in iOS Simulator Directory where your files are located.. Are you want to show downloaded file right?

Comment: I did it :) yes, I've found directory and showed file in webview for test (and in finder as well) - but how would one check downloaded file on real device? if app downloaded let say pdf, how could I display it in real device?

Comment: I don't have a Mac running right now to quote the details, but in Xcode you can go to the attached device and ask that it's directory structure be downloaded to the Mac, then inspect that downloaded structure.  A little tedious, but you should only need to do it once or twice.

Answer (score 0):

So I downloaded, saved it and displayed in `UIWebView` successfully :) I put this inside succes block of request operation:

```
NSString *path = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[[operation.response.allHeaderFields objectForKey:@"Content-Disposition"] substringFromIndex:22]];
path = [path substringToIndex:path.length-1];
[operation.responseData writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]]];
[self.view addSubview:webView];
```